# El despido de dos de las personas más importantes de la comunidad de Stack Exchange: ¿En qué se ha convertido Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión, comunidad, meta-stackexchange, empresa

Esta tarde, tanto Shog9 como Robert Cartaino, colaboradores de StackExchange por más de 10 años y de las personas que han hecho la comunidad de SE como es, [han sido despedidos sin ceremonias y por sorpresa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9). No ha habido ningún tipo de post oficial al respecto. Se ha sabido porque Shog9 ha tweeteado que se encontraba en búsqueda de trabajo por sorpresa.

Tras la conmoción inicial, JuanM (presumiblemente dándole voz a SE) ha escrito un (a mi juicio, deleznable) [post como respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342045/622229) en el que decía que éstas acciones son parte de un esfuerzo para continuar creciendo y mantener a la comunidad como un actor importante en las decisiones.

Personalmente me siento insultado.

A la vista de la situación (Parece que a SE ya no le interesa la opinión de sus usuarios *meta*, sólo su capacidad de generar tráfico), quisiera saber cuál es el futuro de SOes. ¿Nos convertiremos en *El nuevo SO, pero en Español*? ¿Seremos una máquina de hacer deberes, sin control de calidad ni capacidad de mejorar las cosas? En caso de estar en contra de estos cambios, ¿Qué puede hacer uno al respecto?

De nuevo personalmente, me da mucha pena que el sitio en el que he aprendido tanto de la profesión que amo, y en el que he conocido a gente brillante deje de valorar la capacidad de sus usuarios y únicamente nos tenga como generadores de tráfico.

---

En un aparte quería mandar un agradecimiento hacia Shog9. Nunca he hablado con él directamente, pero sí he sido testigo tardío de muchas de las cosas que ha hecho por la comunidad, y siento tristeza por ver que sus más de diez años de dedicación han sido desechados con tanta frialdad.

Comment: No es como que vaya a afectar en mucho al sitio pero yo he decidido eliminar todas mis cuentas de Stack Exchange, lo venía considerando desde hace mucho y les di el beneficio de la duda, pero para mi una empresa que valora los números por encima de su gente es una empresa de la que no quiero ser parte

Comment: El despido de Shog9 y Robert Cartaino es algo grotesco, no se me ocurre ningún motivo lógico por el que esto pueda pasar. El sentir de toda la comunidad creo que va de la indignación a la rabia y sorpresa. A mí se me han quitado las ganas de creer en el proyecto.

Comment: Vuelvo de vacaciones y veo que las cosas en SE en lugar de ir a mejor, van claramente a peor. Como bien dice @fedorqui, dan ganas de abandonar completamente a un empresa que trata asi a trabajadores y usuarios...

Comment: Me da la sensación de que se quieren quitar a la gente que da voz a la comunidad y que mas trabaja por ella para mejorarla para poder tener marionetas que solo obedezcan. Como comenta en su post Shog9 veía a los usuarios como sus "jefes" mientras que SE quiere ser el que realmente manda, la comunidad parece que queda en segundo plano. Una pena...

Comment: También Jon Ericson deja de ser empleado de la compañia. En su caso, por decisión propia; ya tiene trabajo en otra empresa. En primera instancia no me agradan estas noticias, pero es algo normal en cualquier empresa sobre todo luego de un cambio de presidente al que se le han encomendado hacer cambios. Seguramente a todos ellos les irá bien. En cuanto a en que se ha convertido SO, aún está por verse, pero seguramente mucho tendrá que ver "la bola" (los que participamos en meta y los que no, pero que sí lo hacen en los sitios principales, pero sobre todo en SO)

Answer (score 13):

No he tratado a @Shog9 como casi a nadie de esta comunidad. Pero me da mucha pena la actitud que comentas y es una decepción, porque hoy por hoy Stackoverflow es una comunidad única para encontrar respuestas a problemas, para aprender, etc. Cualquier proyecto en el que importen más los números que las personas está destinado al fracaso. Si Stackoverflow toma ese camino no será la excepción.

Simplemente quiero traducir [la respuesta de Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342059/376485) al castellano, a la [pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/376485) a la que haces referencia más arriba, para que tengan la oportunidad de leerla los miembros de Stackoverflow en español:

> No, gracias a vosotros.
>
> Mi cabeza sigue girando; nada dura para siempre, pero ... A veces nos
>   engañamos pensando que podría ser. Pero una cosa sé: estoy
>   profundamente conmovido por este hilo.
>
> Siempre los he considerado a ustedes, las personas que componen Stack
>   Overflow, como mi jefe, mi líder en este trabajo.
>
> Y ... mierda ... ustedes han sido el mejor jefe para el que he tenido
>   el privilegio de trabajar. Rápido con elogios y críticas
>   constructivas, nunca demasiado ocupado para hablar, conocedor de una
>   variedad aparentemente infinita de temas, pero nunca demasiado bueno
>   para educar.
>
> He aprendido mucho de ustedes a lo largo de los años. Entré en esto lo
>   más verde posible, pero todos fueron pacientes y comprensivos.
>
> Me han enseñado lo que es la verdadera colaboración.
>
> Gracias por permitirme servir estos últimos 9 años. Gracias, gracias,
>   gracias.

Answer (score 3):

No conozco a Shog9 ni a Robert Cartaino, por lo que no tengo nada malo ni bueno que decir de ellos. Es decir, no voy a romper una lanza a su favor. Carezco del contexto necesario para saber si sus despidos fueron merecidos o inmerecidos, coherentes o disparatados, justificados o injustificados.

Pero si que conozco la red StackExchange. Si debo escoger una palabra para describir esta comunidad, la palabra sería "conocimiento". Pero últimamente no he ejercido el conocimiento con esta red: Me he informado poco y mal sobre los incidentes relacionados en los que esta comunidad se ha visto envuelta en los últimos meses y lo poco que me he informado no ha sido de mi agrado.

Hace centurias se creía que el cerebro era un órgano que el cuerpo usaba para refrigerar la sangre y que el corazón era el órgano que dotaba de alma, voluntad y raciocinio a los seres humanos… hoy sabemos que no es así pero hay muchas cosas que seguimos sin saber del cerebro: si vemos un cerebro en un frasco, no sabremos si era de mujer u hombre, de una u otra etnia, de una u otra nacionalidad, de izquierdas o de derechas, liberal o progresista, rico o pobre… porque es un órgano que se usa para pensar no para *ser*.

¿Por qué es relevante esta anécdota? Porque a pesar de que esta comunidad es una comunidad dedicada al **conocimiento de la gente**, se está volviendo una comunidad regida por lo que **es la gente**. Ya no basta con *saber* algo, tienes que *ser* algo para que el conocimiento sea válido. Parece que volveremos a los tiempos oscuros en que usaremos el cerebro para refrigerar la sangre y el corazón para pensar.

No tengo ni idea de qué les ha pasado a Shog9 ni a Robert Cartaino, pero sospecho que puede tener que ver con esta deriva… ¿serán substituidos por unas personas que cumplan con ciertas características de *ser* en lugar de cumplir con las características de *pensar*? Pues no tengo ni idea, ojalá mi sospecha no se corrobore.

Comment: Tu preocupación está bien fundada pero el motivo no es más que un subproducto del verdadero problema: SE ha cambiado de rumbo hacia la *máxima* rentabilidad posible. Si para conseguirla hay que recortar gastos de Comunidad despidiendo CMs, adherirse a ciertas políticas (como la que tú dices) para generar más tráfico y relajar la moderación para, de nuevo, generar más tráfico, no les temblará la mano. La comunidad de meta es, para ellos, un estorbo que se opone a este rumbo.